# jQuery: change css of the page number when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to figure how to change the css class of #pg2 to 'active' when the user scrolls to #bx2 and change #pg3 to 'active' when the user scrolls to #bx3 and so on...

```
<ul id="navi" style="position:fixed;top:0">
<li><a href="#bx1" id="pg1" class="active">1</a></li>
<li><a href="#bx2" id="pg2" class="">2</a></li>
<li><a href="#bx3" id="pg3" class="">3</a></li>
...
<li><a href="#bx00" id="pg100" class="">100</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tallbigblock" id="bx1">...</div>
<div class="tallbigblock" id="bx2">...</div>
<div class="tallbigblock" id="bx3">...</div>
...
<div class="tallbigblock" id="bx100">...</div>
```

Here is my jquery:

```
$( window ).scroll( function() {

var t = $( "#bx1" ).offset().top;
if( $(this).scrollTop() > t )
{
    $( "#navi li a" ).removeClass( "active" ).hasClass( "active" );
    $( "#pg1" ).addClass( "active" );
}

var t = $( "#bx2" ).offset().top;
if( $(this).scrollTop() > t )
{
    $( "#navi li a" ).removeClass( "active" ).hasClass( "active" );
    $( "#pg2" ).addClass( "active" );
}

var t = $( "#bx3" ).offset().top;
if( $(this).scrollTop() > t )
{
    $( "#navi li a" ).removeClass( "active" ).hasClass( "active" );
    $( "#pg3" ).addClass( "active" );
}

});
```

The thing is, if I have a 50 ".tallbigblock" divs... or dynamically generated ".tallbigblock" divs...

I've been trying to figure out how to make the jquery work for *n* number of ".tallbigblock" divs without coding the jquery for each div manually... 
hope you guys can help me out...

Thanks a bunch!!

Answer (score 1):

This is untested but the only difference from the original code is that it's not hard-coded and only allows one box to be active at a time.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();

    $('#navi li a').removeClass('active');

    $('.tallbigblock').each(function()
    {
        if(scrollTop > $(this).offset().top)
        {
            $('#pg'+this.id.split('x')[1]).addClass('active');

            return false; // this breaks the each loop
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code @summoner posted, I've modified and tested the following code:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

  var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
  $(".tallbigblock").each(function() {
    if(scrollTop > $(this).offset().top)
    {
      var i = $(this).attr('id');
      var nid = "#pg" + i.replace("bx", "");
      $("#navi li a").removeClass("active").hasClass("active");
      $(nid).addClass("active");        
    }
  });
});
```